# Xamarin.ios app crash on HttpClient async request (SIGABRT: The socket is not connected)

Tags: xamarin, websocket, xamarin.ios, httpclient

I have a problem that I'm using HttpClient to fetch big JSON content from an API, in an async task. The problem happens when I lock the device screen while the app is in the background doing the request. If I open the app again, it crashes (SIGABRT: The socket is not connected)

This is the project on github:
https://github.com/aproram/httpclient-bug

In order to replicate the issue, these are the steps to replicate it exactly:
-Make sure the app is terminated and not running in the background
-open the app
-push the home button. 
-lock the phone
-unlock the phone
-open the app again, it will crash.

Crash Stack Traces (Using AppHockey):

```
Socket.EndReceive (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult)
NetworkStream.EndRead (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult)

NetworkStream.EndRead (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult)
Stream+<>c.<BeginEndReadAsync>b__45_1 (System.IO.Stream stream, System.IAsyncResult asyncResult)
TaskFactory`1+FromAsyncTrimPromise`1[TResult,TInstance].Complete (TInstance thisRef, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] endMethod, System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization)
MobileAuthenticatedStream.InnerRead (System.Boolean sync, System.Int32 requestedSize, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
AsyncProtocolRequest.InnerRead (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
AsyncProtocolRequest.StartOperation (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
MobileAuthenticatedStream.StartOperation (Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream+OperationType type, Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
BufferedReadStream.ProcessReadAsync (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
WebReadStream.ReadAsync (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
FixedSizeReadStream.ProcessReadAsync (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
WebReadStream.ReadAsync (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)

HttpWebRequest.RunWithTimeoutWorker[T] (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] workerTask, System.Int32 timeout, System.Action abort, System.Func`1[TResult] aborted, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts)
WebResponseStream.ReadAsync (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Stream.CopyToAsyncInternal (System.IO.Stream destination, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
HttpContent.LoadIntoBufferAsync (System.Int64 maxBufferSize)
HttpClient.SendAsyncWorker (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption completionOption, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
ViewController.FetchtheJSON ()
AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0 (System.Object state)
NSAsyncSynchronizationContextDispatcher.Apply ()
(wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate)
UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName)
Application.Main (System.String[] args)
```

Not sure if there's something missing I should have done.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add null checks, since the request is timing out.

It's not listening for the response, and thus returns a null. You could do something like this:

```
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
if (content != null)
{
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(content))
    {
        var content_json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        if (content_json != null)
            txtbox1.Text = content_json;
    }
}
```

Your crash should go away.

Comment: Have you tried to replicate the issue and to try that solution ? It doesn't solve it, unfortuantely. The problem comes within ReadAsStreamAsync() itself, not after the return to my code...